# <?php woocommerce_cart_totals(); ?> is somehow displaying twice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce shopping cart page is acting very strange.

I just updated my theme ( X | Theme v3.2.5 ) and woocommerce ( v2.3.8 )

So I am running the most current versions.

For some reason, since the update my cart totals are now displaying twice on my cart page.

I have two subtotal columns, two proceed to checkout buttons, two empty cart buttons, etc.

When I look at the HTML, it's literally duplicated.

```
<div class="cart-collaterals">
 <div class="cart_totals ">
 <div class="cart_totals ">
</div>
```

Obviously `cart_totals` has more HTML underneath, but you get the idea.

On the actual cart.php page I can locate this php:

```
<?php woocommerce_cart_totals(); ?>
```

only one time. Here is all the markup from the cart.php page:

```
<div class="cart-collaterals">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' ); ?>

    <?php woocommerce_cart_totals(); ?>

</div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart' ); ?>
```

Is there any way to ensure that this php is only being ran one time?

I might try to just limit the height of the CSS container, but that's not the right fix...

Comment: Is it possible that, as part of the update, they moved the cart total to the "woocommerce_cart_collaterals" action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In their latest update, they must have moved the cart total to the `woocommerce_cart_collaterals`, which means it is now printed once in this action, and once in your code.

Comment: THANKS! 

I uploaded a file without the extra `<?php woocommerce_cart_totals(); ?>` and that got rid of the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with TM Extra Options plugin on Themeforest. In the plugin remove `<?php woocommerce_cart_totals(); ?>` in the templates/cart/cart.php file (it's at the bottom) and you will remove duplicate "Cart Totals". Hope this helps someone.